# How to create a simple Drupal module that updates a custom node field

Tags: 8, hooks

I have a custom node type "**product**" which has a custom Decimal type field "**field_price**".

I would like to create a simple module in Drupal 8 to set this value to 10.75 every time I **create or update** a node.

**edit**

I have now restructured the module as follows. These are the files / folder structure I have (excluding the .info.yml) :

Module folder:
**/modules/updateprices**

Routing.yml:
**/modules/updateprices/update_prices.routing.yml**

```
Routing.yml code:
update_prices:
    path: /updateprices
    defaults:
        _controller: 'Drupal\updateprices\Controller\UpdatePricesController::update_prices_node_presave'
    requirements:
        _permission: 'access content'
```

Controller code:
**/modules/updateprices/src/Controller/UpdatePricesController.php**

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\updateprices\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;

class UpdatePricesController  {
        function update_prices_node_presave(EntityInterface $entity) {

          $entity_type = 'node';
          $bundles = ['product'];

          $fld_price = 'field_price';
          if ($entity->getEntityTypeId() != $entity_type || !in_array($entity->bundle(), $bundles)) {
            return;
          }
             $entity->{$fld_price}->setValue(10.75);
        } 
}
```

I am now getting an error:

> ReflectionException: Class
>   Drupal\updateprices\Controller\UpdatePricesController does not
>   exist in ReflectionMethod->__construct() (line 123 of
>   /home/website.com/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityResolverManager.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hooks, in a module, only work inside the .module file.

You don't need a controller nor a routing file here, these are used for creating pages.

/modules/updateprices/**updateprices.module**

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;

function update_prices_node_presave(EntityInterface $entity) {

  $entity_type = 'node';
  $bundles = ['product'];

  $fld_price = 'field_price';
  if ($entity->getEntityTypeId() != $entity_type || !in_array($entity->bundle(), $bundles)) {
    return;
  }
  $entity->{$fld_price}->setValue(10.75);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did all of the above. I have restructured the question to show the state of the module now. Still getting error.

Comment: @ibexy updated my answer based on  your update.